# How can I reduce the number of jobs in a Buildkite pipeline upload?

Tags: pipeline, cicd, buildkite

I am working on a Buildkite CICD pipeline that occasionally has too many jobs to run and results in the following error:

```
Failed to upload and process pipeline: Pipeline upload rejected: The number of jobs in this upload exceeds your organization limit of 500. Please break the upload into batches below this limit, or contact support to discuss an increase.
```

Is there a way to batch upload the pipeline steps for a single pipeline in order to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by refactoring the pipeline to use '**Build Matrices**': https://buildkite.com/docs/pipelines/build-matrix and '**Group steps**' in the configuration: https://buildkite.com/docs/pipelines/group-step.